# Php detect if browser is running on server or client

Tags: php, server, localhost, client

i built a project for a client and the program will run from a base server, while other client system will connect to the base server ip and access the servers localhost,
am validating a license key using the systems hard disk id, but i want to validate only the base server, while the client server systems will skip the validations, i.e "if system is base server run script" 
i want my client to be able to connect to as many as possible client systems while using the same license key

how can i achieve this with PHP

Comment: I've read the question a couple of times now but I still don't really understand what you're asking. Clients connecting to a base server and accessing the servers localhost? Are you talking about remote desktop? Also, _"i want my client to be able to connect to as many as possible client systems"_ - Wasn't it the clients that connected to the server? Please rewrite your question with a proper explanation of the setup and what you're trying to do. It's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: yes i mean remote desktop,
there will be a system, on that system i wil install xampp server and the project will be on the xampp, then other system will be connected to it remotely, and access the same application, 

so i want to validate only the system that has xampp installed on it. dont know if am explaining it well but just to detect if the system is connecting to a remote desktop or the system is one, other systems are connecting to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved this myself, thanks to all to that contribute

the question is "when connecting to a server, an application that validates user using hardisk id, will it check the hard disk id of all connected systems?"

the answer is "No"

Answer (score 0):

If your other servers connect to your application directly, you should see different results when you echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in your application.
You could use that to decide whether to run the script:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "SERVER_IP") { ... }
```

If you connect to the computer remotely, and then access the application, this will probably in all cases be the localhost address. 
In that case, I recommend that you debug the entire $_SERVER variable and check if there are variables that differ, for example $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']?

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: yes i mean remote desktop, there will be a system, on that system i wil install xampp server and the project will be on the xampp, then other system will be connected to it remotely, and access the same application, so i want to validate only the system that has xampp installed on it. dont know if am explaining it well but just to detect if the system is connecting to a remote desktop or the system is the one, other systems are connecting to, that is to detect if system is the host or client

Comment: If your other servers connect to your application directly, you should see different results when you echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in your application. If you connect to the computer remotely, and then access the application, it will probably always be localhost address.You could debug the entire $_SERVER variable and check if there are variables that differ, for example $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']?

Comment: @Benjamin, I updated the previous answer, does it answer your question?